# Derivative of Matrix elements w.r.t. to scalar

Tags: matrix-calculus

First of all, excuse the stupid question. Unfortunately, I couldn't find something similar already asked.

Consider the matrix

$$
A(r_1, r_2) = \begin{pmatrix} r_1^2 & 3 \\ 2 & r_2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

I'd like to know how I can get the Jacobian of this matrix. I'd suggest it's something like:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial A(r_1, r_2)}{\partial r_1} &= \begin{pmatrix} 2r_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\frac{\partial A(r_1, r_2)}{\partial r_2} &= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$

But what mathematical object is the Jacobian of the Matrix $A$? Is it a matrix with three dimensions? Any help or hints for useful links are really appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Usages

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not define your "space" of matrices. The easiest way to think of $2\times 2$ matrices is as $\mathbb{R}^4$ vectors. Then, the Jacobian of $A:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^4$ is a $4\times 2$ matrix:
$$
J_A=\begin{pmatrix}
2r_1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you want to work on these derivatives as matrices, you can think of operations such as the *reshape* of *Matlab*, but it is not clear e.g. how the chain rule would work then.